# How to solve this, SQL beetwen 2 date, in SQL 'OR', the result is mismatch

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter

This is my following code:

```
$this->db->where('plb_db_prod.tpb_header.KODE_DOKUMEN_PABEAN = 27 AND plb_db_prod.tpb_header.KODE_KANTOR_TUJUAN = 050100 OR plb_db_prod.tpb_header.KODE_DOKUMEN_PABEAN = 40 OR plb_db_prod.tpb_header.KODE_DOKUMEN_PABEAN = 16');

$this->db->where('plb_db_prod.tpb_header.TANGGAL_AJU >= '.$start_date.' AND plb_db_prod.tpb_header.TANGGAL_AJU <= '.$end_date);
```

Comment: Can you please make it more readable?

Comment: Which database engine tool? mySql? Sql Server? Postgre? Oracle?

Comment: Sql Server @ARr0w

Answer (score 0):

then this code will give you a guide to get your following result or when you want to update something between these days.

date format i am using here is `mm/dd/yyyy`

```
Select tbl1.* 
from tbl1 
where tbl1.Datecolumn between '8/12/2017' and '12/1/2017';
```

here Between has `FromDate` and `ToDate`

for update you can try the same logic.

```
Update tbl1 
set tbl1.Column = 'somedata' 
where tbl1.datecolumn between '8/12/2017' and '12/1/2017';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Query to find the dates between Start and End;

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MY_TABLE 
WHERE 
    MY_DATE BETWEEN Start_Date AND End_Date
```